# Azure stream analytics create dynamic queries through code

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have a web application which allows user to create alert rules on some sensor values in the browser UI. As a result, user can create any number of alert rules on the sensor values. AWS IoT core allows to create multiple alert rules using the JS SDK. Similar thing I was looking into Azure Stream analytics[ASA] but I found some blockers as listed below:-

1. ASA doesn't provide JS sdk to create queries at runtime. At least I couldn't find it over the internet. Please help if there is any that allows to create queries at runtime.
2. If point 1 stands true, does ASA allow me to create multiple queries. For example, I need to create multiple alerts with varying conditions. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your original need, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-threshold-based-rules) details a pattern to implement dynamic rules via a reference data set. So one single query, loading rule definitions from a database or file.

As for 1 and 2, ASA has a [.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.streamanalytics?view=azure-dotnet), or a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/). But there is no JavaScript SDK.

Comment: I don't have a static reference data set not the operators are static. The rules should be created in code based some business logic and passed on to ASA as Query. I don't think your approach with reference data set will work.

Comment: The dynamic rules pattern allows you to serve rules that are created dynamically by users. The reference dataset is just a table in Azure SQL (or file in a storage account) that stores the definition of these rules including its scope (deviceId), the operator (via an enumeration of the rules your support, for example GREATER, GREATEROREQUAL..) the field on which it is applied (with dynamic access in the query via GetRecordPropertyValue) and the value of the threshold. So a record in that table could look like (DeviceId, 'Temperature', 'GREATEROREQUAL', 70). Then in the query you join over it

Comment: When a user creates a rule in your UI, your app will insert a row into that table/file with all those required info (scope, operator, field, value). That table/file is your reference dataset in ASA.

Comment: Regarding your comment on inserting reference data in the table, lets say I have inserted 1000 JSON objects in the table. Now, will all 1000 JSON object reference data wll be evaluated by ASA on each streamed event? If yes, I need the result to be 1000 objects as all the 1000 reference data rules are different saved in the table.

Comment: To avoid doing cartesian joins it's better to have some reference to a scope in your rules yes. The narrower the rule the better in terms of join performance, but then you may have to deal with the limits of reference dataset in ASA (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data#size-limitation).

Comment: Another way to see this: do the rules that your users create need to be checked on every incoming event? If not, what is the key that defines that scope? Then put that key in the rule definition and join over it in the query.

Comment: There is not a single key. Since it's dynamic the user can select any number of keys and any condition.I still can't imagine how will this work if start putting all these in reference data and each event will have to go through each of the reference data. Is it feasible?

Comment: This is not a technical issue here, but a design one. If there is no key/scope, from a design perspective that means that users are expecting rules to be applied to every event coming in. If this is not the case, then users should be able to establish a scoping pattern to say that rule A applies to scope 1 and rule B applies to scope 2. If it's not a device, it's a fleet of devices, or the building they're in, or the model/type of it, or another attribute of that device. Are you telling me your users don't expect that, or that you don't have that attribute in your payload?